# Unload millions of rows of data from DOMO into Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, domo

Is there a way to unload hundreds of millions of rows from DOMO into Snowflake.

I know Snowflake has a Connector but that's from Snowflake to DOMO, I need to do the opposite. I tried exporting in DOMO to a CSV but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Domo expert, but this seems to be what you need:

https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043437093-Snowflake-Writeback-Connector

You could also use the S3 writeback connector to get a file out to S3 and then import that into Snowflake, but the Snowflake Writeback Connector seems to do all of that work for you.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWalton - our co doesn't have the Domo's Integration Cloud plan so this won't work for us, but maybe it will work for someone else so I've selected it as the best answer!